# VBA copy data from different sheets from row above where cell text "subtotal"

Tags: excel, vba

> Want to copy Data from Different worksheets to a sheet called
>   "Summary". Data needs to be copy from one Row above (where row has text
>   "subtotal") to Row/Column A2. Below is my VBA code, but getting error MESSAGE " Compiler error, Else without If ", not sure what i am missing.
>   please help me.

---

```
 Sub CombineData()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Summary" And Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "1" Or Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "4" Or Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "6" Or Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "7" Then

    Sht.Select

    'LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    Set MyRng = Range(Cells(1, "d"), Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In MyRng
    If cell.Value = "Subtotal" Then cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

    .Range("A2", "M&MyRng").Copy 

    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste         
    Sht.Select
    Range("p1").ClearContents

    Else
    End If
    Next Sht
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some flaws.

1. **Identation**. Code inside Sub, For, If needs to be identated with tab or 4 spaces.
2. **End**. Each `Sub` has `End Sub`, each `If` as and `End If`, each `For` has and `End For`
3. **Values**. Instead of copying and pasting, you can set `.Range() = new_value`
4. **String comparison**. `If cell.Value = "Subtotal"` will fail if the user writes subtotal or SUBTOTAL. That is why I prefer to lowercase the cell value using `LCase()` function.

You may want to use the following code

```
 Sub CombineData()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    'Identify Sheet called Summary
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Set wsSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name <> "Summary" And (Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "1" Or Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "4" Or Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "6" Or Left(Sht.Name, 1) = "7") Then
            For Each cell In Sht.UsedRange.Cells
                If LCase(cell.Value) = "subtotal" Then
                    'Copy cell above subtotal to the last row in column A of Summary sheet
                    wsSummary.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
                    Sht.Range("p1") = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dr Yunke,  I have copies your vba code, having  error message on line :  Set MyRng = Sht.Range(Cells(1, "d"), Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))

Comment: the error message are  : Run time error 1004 .  Method "Range" of object_worksheet failed . Please help me.

Comment: Ok, delete that line and modify the For like  `For Each cell In Sht.UsedRange.Cells` check my edited code above

Comment: Hi Dr Yunke, sorry still VBA not working, just to clarify, I need to copy all sheets data from row above  "Subtotal"  column from A to P to the Summary sheet ( paste data starting from row/column A3 of summary sheet. It will very helpful if you could review the vba code you posted and advise me accordingly. I really appreciate your help , thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Your code will only copy the cell above subtotal from sheets whose name starts with 1, 4, 6 or 7. If you want to include all sheets no matter their name (except Summary), you need to just use `If Sht.Name <> "Summary" Then`

Comment: And then each value for cell above Subtotal it finds, it will copy its value to the last row used in column A in Summary sheet.

Comment: If you want to modify what your code does, then you should ask another question. It seems this question solved your compile problem. Please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much Dr Yunke, your VBA is working as coded. Appreciate your help.  if you please advise vba code for -  copy range cell from above subtotal to column P1 .

Comment: subtotal text in column D

Comment: If you want to copy the cell above subtotal to the same sheet in cell P1, you should delete line `Sht.Range("p1").ClearContents`, and add a line below `wsSummary.Range`. The line to add should be  `Sht.Range("p1") =cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value`. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Hi Dr Yunke , sorry for the confusion , I want to copy individual sheets data Rang From  cell above subtotal to P1 and past to summary sheet. example . if "Subtotal" text in D7  then Range should be from D6 to P1  (P1 cell is always static), but row in D column varies. Please advice VBA code . I really appreciate patient and answering my question. thank you so mcuh.

Comment: I edited the code in the answer and does that, you need to refresh the page.

Comment: could you please advise vba code to select range cell above subtotal to P1 instead of  cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value . thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is wrong with `Sht.Range("p1") = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value` ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your VBA code: Sht.Range("p1") = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value.   I don't want to copy to same sheet P1, sorry for the confusion. Looking for VBA code that can copy cell range  ( Row cell above "subtotal" upto row 4, Column cell above subtotal i.e. D to P). I am sure you can advise me this VBA code, I don't know how to code for this selection in your above code. Thanks you so much, I am very close to achive this codeing with your help.

Comment: Please ask another question, and we would be happy to help

Comment: Thanks for your offer. Sorry I have to wait few days as I have exceed the question limit for the day.

Comment: wsSummary.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Range(cell.Offset(-1, 0), cell(4, 16)).Value

Comment: Hi Dr Yunke,  my above VBA is not working, please help me.